# Beginner here - Clicker game timers reset

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so I'm trying to make a pretty simple clicker game, to learn some basic javascript.
Everything works ALMOST fine so far... I have multiple businesses that produce money over time (i've got timers for every business).
Problem is, if you refresh the businesses' page, the production stops and you must start it over again. 
For example, I have a "Coffee shop", that produces x$ every y seconds.
The production is triggered by clicking a button.
What I try to do, is.. if you start the production and refresh the page, the production after refresh should be automatically triggered with the previous remaining time.

**This is what I'm trying to do:**

***- Here is the timer for the Coffee Shop:***

```
     // ========== Coffee shops timer ================ //
    var cafeTimer = 10;
    if(localStorage.cafeTimer) {cafeTimer = localStorage.cafeTimer}
    document.getElementById("dispWaitCafe").innerHTML = cafeTimer;

    function startTimer3(secs3) {
        timeInSecs3 = parseInt(secs3)-1;
        ticker3 = setInterval("tick3()",1000); 
        waitingC = 1;
    }
    function tick3() {
        var secs3 = timeInSecs3;
        if (secs3 > 0) {
        timeInSecs3--;
        }
        else {
        clearInterval(ticker3);
        secs3 = +cafeTimer;
        waitingC = 0;
        cafeButton.style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
        dispWaitCafe.innerHTML = secs3;
```

***- Here is the button that starts production:***

```
cafeButton.onclick = function() { if(cafeLevel > 0) { if(waitingC < 1) {
    setTimeout(function() { money = +money + +cafeProd;
    displayCash.innerHTML = numberWithDots(Math.round(money*100)/100);
    checkupcolors();
    localStorage.money = money; 
    clearInterval(cafeFrame); 
    cafeBar.value = 0; }, +cafeTimer*1000);
    startTimer3(+cafeTimer);
    var cafeFrame = setInterval("cafeframe()",10);
    cafeButton.style.backgroundColor = "#FF6666";
    } }
}
```

**- I also have a progress bar for the timer:**

```
var cafeBar = document.getElementById("cafeBar");
cafeBar.max = +cafeTimer;
function cafeframe() { 
    cafeBar.value += 0.01; 
}
```

***-This is what i tried to add under the cafeTimer declaration:***

```
if(localStorage.cafeTimeleft) { cafeTimer = localStorage.cafeTimeleft;
    if(cafeLevel > 0) { if(waitingC < 1) {
    setTimeout(produceCafe, +cafeTimer*1000);
    startTimer3(+cafeTimer);
    var cafeFrame = setInterval("cafeframe()",10);
    cafeButton.style.backgroundColor = "#FF6666";
    } }
    if(localStorage.cafeTimer) { cafeTimer = localStorage.cafeTimer }
    localStorage.removeItem("cafeTimeleft");
}
```

(produceCafe is the same function as the one used in the onclick above)
Besides the code above, i added `timeLeft = secs3;` and i put in in localStorage everytime the timer above does "dispWaitCafe.innerHTML = secs3;"

I dont know, am I missing something here? It seems that i just screwed up things with my additions. Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: OK i put "ice" instead of "cafe" in the code I said i added. Just look at it as if it was "cafeTimeLeft, cafeTimer, etc"

Comment: You can edit your own question to correct typos.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is you create an onbeforeunload handler where you store the remaining timer length for all your businesses:

```
window.onbeforeunload += function(e) {
    //store the remaining timer length
};
```

Then on window.Load, you instantiate the timers with the remaining time.

```
window.onload += function(e){
    //restart the timers with the remaining time.
}
```

Note: this PAUSES the timers. If you want your user to be able to idle with the window closed (like many clickers do), you have to store the exact systemtime during `window.onbeforeunload()`, then calculate how many timers could have run since then on `window.load()`.